# Why is the governor perplexed after hearing the doctor's question about releasing prisoners?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-voorman-problem

In the award-winning short movie [The Voorman Problem](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1998355/) the governor informs doctor Williams that he doesn't know Voorman's crime, because of the computer system malfuction.

This leads to the following dialog, closing this scene ([source](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/arts/english/currentstudents/undergraduate/modules/screenwriting/voorman_shooting_script.pdf)):

> DOCTOR WILLIAMS
>   But how will you know when to
>   release the prisoners?
>
> BENTLEY is flummoxed.
>
> GOVERNOR BENTLEY "Release?" "The prisoners?"

Why is the governor so perplexed by this question? It looks like the idea of releasing prisoners is completely strange to him. It's really in contrast with the rest of their conversation, that seems to be completely normal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my theory: You're right about the conversation being normal up to that point. But also notice that Doctor Williams' conversation with his wife is normal until he mentions Belgium. His wife is perplexed by the concept of Belgium *just like the governor is perplexed by the concept of releasing prisoners*, which makes me think that **Voorman did that too.** And Voorman supplies the reason:

> I rather like prison. And prisoners are more fun than well-fed congregations. Yet you amuse me more than most, Doctor.

Voorman, a bored God, wanted to remain in prison, so he probably wiped out all the prisoners' records *himself* and then **erased the concept of releasing them**, to boot. But since Williams amuses him more now, he chooses to get out of there and assume his life.